# Jenkins-Python - Ejecutar script .py a traves de CMD

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test, jenkins

Quisiera saber como ejecutar un script .py (prueba automatizada de GUI con Selenium en Python) desde un comando de Windows.

Si abro el cmd y hago:

cd C:\Users\abgro\CyberGuardian Tests\Selenium - Pytest\es-testing\Chrome
pytest test_ejemplo.py

Se ejecuta el script de pruebas perfectamente.

Entonces desde Jenkins, en *Build Steps* -> *Ejecutar un comando de Windows* (sin colocarle mas nada en los pasos previos, solo build steps) me dice que "pytest" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

[image: Comandos de Windows]

[image: Output de ejecucion]

Todo lo que he visto, incluso colocando la segunda linea como la coloco (la de *pytest test_ejemplo.py* ) funciona, no se por que en este caso me sale error.
He probado colocando en la segunda linea, en lugar de *pytest test_ejemplo.py* -> *start /b pytest test_ejemplo.py* ya que *start* si es un comando de Windows y en teoria ejecutaria el programa en la misma ventana pero tampoco (tambien probe otros comandos como *exec*, *start /D* pero nada...)

Comment: Me aparece el mismo error y estoy buscando como slucionarlo

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado `pytest` en Jenkins?